# Adding rows to table in asp.net by click on link button using jQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net

Here I have a table:

```
            <table border="1" border-style="dashed" width="80%" id='tblAddBirthdays'>
            <tr>
            <th>First Name</th>
            <th>Last Name</th>
            </tr>
            <tr id="tr">
            <td><asp:TextBox ID="txFirstName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></td>
            <td><asp:TextBox ID ="txLastName" runat="server" /></td>
            <td><asp:DropDownList ID="dlMonth" runat="server" /></td>
            <td><asp:DropDownList ID="dlDate" runat="server" /></td>
            <td><asp:DropDownList ID="dlYear" runat="server" /></td>
            <td><asp:DropDownList ID="dlAgeRange" runat="server" /></td>
            <td><asp:DropDownList ID="dlRelationship" runat="server" /></td>
            <td><asp:DropDownList ID="dlGender" runat="server" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

and link Button:

```
 <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkLess" runat="server" Text="(<<)Less "  OnClientClick="JavaScript: return false;" />
        <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkMore" runat="server" Text="More(>>)"  OnClientClick="jQuery:add()" />&
```

I want to write jQuery code to add and delete rows to the table, I am trying for two days now and it's still not working. Can anybody help?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be use DataTable. (Jquery Datatable) [Jquery Datatable](http://datatables.net/)

Answer (score 0):

the better thing to do is to use some client side pulgin like Baran said, like datatable or jqgrid

but if u insist in that the native javascript has some interfaces for that 
to delete a row http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_table_deleterow.asp
to add a row http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_table_insertrow.asp

from here your real task will be putting the right data in the right place. there are full examples in those links

Comment: Can I Use Asp.net Grid Control, if so , how it is done, pls reply ASAP

Comment: my friend, the asp grid renders an html table, so you can use it just as it, the only thing is that in your jquery selector after selecting the tablename you need to select the tbody like $(".mytbl tbody"); PS you can peep here to see other things i did with a grid view so that you'll see that in the end its just an htmltable http://bresleveloper.blogspot.co.il/search?q=grid. keep asking if you need more help